# Table saw blade stops on contact with wood whilst motor keeps running

Tags: table-saw

Table saw blades spins fast, but stops on contact with wood whilst motor keeps running so cant saw wood
Its Rexon Model RM130, 1.6kW, RPM 4800 had not been used for some years 
I have sharpened the blade.
Your advise willbe most helpful

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Is this saw belt drive, geared, or direct drive? Are you sure you have the blade on tightly?

Answer (score 10):

Either the blade is slipping on the arbor or the belt is slipping on a pulley. If the former, tighten it. If the latter, tighten it.

[Paul Logan](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/76824/paul-logan) points out that "if the arbor is tight on the blade and the belt seems fairly tight, replace the belt. As they age the get slick and won't grab the pulley".